# Custom expandable listview searching with child element open in android

Tags: android, expandablelistview, expandablelistadapter, android-filter

I have implemented search functionality on custom expandable listview.Its is working fine means it is giving results as expected.

I have implemented search on parent element of expandable listview.The problem is when I open child element before searching anything and after I write some text criteria in edittext it gives me results with child element open of same position.Means it saves the position of child element while searching.

I don't want this to open it should give me results of parent elements irrespective of child element is opened.

Here is the code of adapter.

```java
package com.ypomumbai.adapter;

import java.text.ParseException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Locale;

import com.android.volley.toolbox.ImageLoader;
import com.android.volley.toolbox.NetworkImageView;
import com.ypomumbai.R;
import com.ypomumbai.activities.responseparser.MemberResponseParser;
import com.ypomumbai.activities.responseparser.YpoOfferResponseParser;
import com.ypomumbai.utills.AppController;
import com.ypomumbai.utills.CommonUtils;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.BaseExpandableListAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class YpoAdapterDemo extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

private LayoutInflater minflt;
ImageLoader imageLoader1 = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
List<YpoOfferResponseParser>mypOfferResponseParsers;

List<YpoOfferResponseParser>mcopyYPOfferResponseParsers;


Activity context;

public YpoAdapterDemo(Activity context,List<YpoOfferResponseParser>mypOfferResponseParsers) {
    this.context = context;
    minflt = (LayoutInflater) context
            .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);

    this.mcopyYPOfferResponseParsers=new ArrayList<YpoOfferResponseParser>();
    this.mcopyYPOfferResponseParsers.addAll(mypOfferResponseParsers);
    this.mypOfferResponseParsers=mypOfferResponseParsers;


}

@Override
public Object getChild(int arg0, int arg1) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView,
        ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    ypochildClass child;
    if(convertView==null){
        convertView = minflt.inflate(R.layout.ypo_offer_child_row,
                null);
        child=new ypochildClass();
        child.offer_description=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_brand_description);
        child.offer_contact=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvContact);
        child.offer_validity=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tvvalid_up_to);

        convertView.setTag(child);
    }
    else{
        child=(ypochildClass)convertView.getTag();
    }
    try{

    child.offer_description.setText(mypOfferResponseParsers.get(groupPosition).details);
    child.offer_contact.setText(mypOfferResponseParsers.get(groupPosition).contact);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.print(e.toString());
    }

    if(mypOfferResponseParsers.get(groupPosition).valid_up_to==null){
        child.offer_validity.setText("-");

    }
    else{
        try {
            child.offer_validity.setText(CommonUtils.getDateFormatted(mypOfferResponseParsers.get(groupPosition).valid_up_to.trim()));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 1;
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return null;
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return mypOfferResponseParsers.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ypoparentClass parentGroup;
    if(convertView==null){
        convertView = minflt.inflate(R.layout.ypo_offer_parent_row,
                null);
        parentGroup=new ypoparentClass();
        parentGroup.ypo_offer_icon=(NetworkImageView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.iv_brand);
        parentGroup.offer_title=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_brand_name);
        parentGroup.offer_category=(TextView)convertView.findViewById(R.id.tv_category_name);

        convertView.setTag(parentGroup);
    }
    else{
        parentGroup=(ypoparentClass)convertView.getTag();
    }
    if (imageLoader1 == null){
        imageLoader1 = AppController.getInstance().getImageLoader();
    }
    try{
    parentGroup.ypo_offer_icon.setImageUrl(mypOfferResponseParsers.get(groupPosition).photo_url, imageLoader1);
    parentGroup.offer_title.setText(mypOfferResponseParsers.get(groupPosition).company);
    parentGroup.offer_category.setText(mypOfferResponseParsers.get(groupPosition).category.name);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.out.print(e.toString());
    }
    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    return false;
}
@Override
public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    super.onGroupExpanded(groupPosition);
}

public void filter(String charText) {
    try{
        charText = charText.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).trim();
        mypOfferResponseParsers.clear();
        if (charText.length() == 0) {
            mypOfferResponseParsers.addAll(mcopyYPOfferResponseParsers);
        } 
        else 
        {
            String filterString;
            String filterSpouseString="";
            String filertIndustry="";
            int i=0;
            for (YpoOfferResponseParser wp : mcopyYPOfferResponseParsers)
            {

                if (wp.company.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText) ) 
                {
                    mypOfferResponseParsers.add(wp);
                }
                else if(wp.category.name.toLowerCase(Locale.getDefault()).contains(charText)){
                    mypOfferResponseParsers.add(wp);
                }
            }
        }
        notifyDataSetChanged();
    }
    catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO: handle exception
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

}
class ypoparentClass{
NetworkImageView ypo_offer_icon;
TextView offer_title;
TextView offer_category;
}
class ypochildClass{
TextView offer_description,offer_validity,offer_contact;
}
```

Can anyone help on this?